# Swing JFrame rendering a webpage with embedded video shows a white page and throws IOException with "invalid URL"

Tags: java, swing, url, embedded-resource

I wonder if I do some mistakes because I do not get the content of the webpage displayed on the `JFrame`. Instead, I only get a white page. The error I got was:

```
java.io.IOException: invalid URL
```

Here is the code for `video.html`:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="video-file.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Vid extends JFrame{

    public Vid(String title){
        super(title);
        setBounds(100, 100, 550, 500);
        Container ControlHost = getContentPane();
        ControlHost.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
        jep.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(jep);
        Dimension ScrollSize = new Dimension(500, 450);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(ScrollSize);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        ControlHost.add(scroll);

        URL HtmlPage = Vid.class.getResource("video.html");
        try {
            jep.setPage(HtmlPage);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To debug this, I suggest printing out the `URL`.

Comment: I think you will be, generally, disappointed with Swing's HTML support (3.x).  I would consider looking at JavaFX instead

Answer (score 0):

Probably problem is in:

```
URL HtmlPage = Vid.class.getResource("video.html");
```

If this file is in your root-level class-path, you should ask for it:

```
URL HtmlPage = Vid.class.getResource("/video.html");
```

Comment: I did try that but still can not see anything! It works well if I enter http://www.google.com insstaed of the path address of my own html file.